# Michael Hartl - Chapter 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been going through Chapter 2 and it's been going well, except that he's asked the reader to show the users first micropost, which seems simple. You can see the Chapter [here](https://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app).

In my `show.html.erb` I've added the following lines:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p

<p>
  <strong>Post:</strong>
  <%= @user.microposts.first %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edi<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

But all I see at /users/1 is "Post: #".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= @user.microposts.first %>` returns a single post object. to render content do this

`<%= @user.microposts.first.content %>`

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively you could override `to_s` so the representation of the post is its content.